# Why I cannot iterate over a list in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to iterate over a list within a function. That list is converted from a yield. However, as I tried to loop over the list, I cannot iterate beyond the first element. get_partitions(key_set) is the yield statement function. Hope someone can help!

```
def brute_force_cow_transport(cows,limit):
    period=[]
    key_set=cows.keys()
    for partition in get_partitions(key_set):
        period.append(partition)

    for trip in period:
        result=[]
        for subtrip in trip:
            weight_subtrip=0
            subList=[]
            for i in range(len(subtrip)):
                weight_subtrip+=cows[subtrip[i]]
                subList+=[subtrip[i]]
            if weight_subtrip>limit:
                break
            else:
                result.append(subList)
        break
    return result
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to provide enough information for us to help you - see the [ask] if you have not already. Which loop is failing? What do you mean by "list is converted from a yield" - do you mean the first loop appending to ``period``? Can you share the code of ``get_partitions`` and sample input of ``cows`` and ``limit``? Are you aware that ``list`` takes an iterable, so you can just do ``period=list(get_partitions(cows.keys()))``?

Comment: @Robo Robok: Can you edit better put definition header in code too ty.